# What is meant by "present thinking" in Goldstein's work on aphasia?

Tags: psycholinguistics, neurolinguistics, aphasiology

I am writing a paper on aphasia and have come across some work by Kurt Goldstein.
Apparently, Goldstein claims that people with aphasia speak without thinking first, and that their speech is not accompanied by "present thinking".
As English is not my first language, I would like to check that I understood what is meant by "present" in this context. Does it simply mean thinking which is happening at the time of speaking?